# java basics garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

is garbage collection algorithm in java "vendor implemented?"

Comment: Do you mean can it differ between different JVMs? I would expect the answer is yes, but to confirm, see if the Garbage Collection method is described in the JLS. I suspect it isn't though.

Comment: In order to allow conservative collectors, there isn't really any constraints that can be placed on the collector (other than, for instance, not collecting objects that are not garbage). Having no GC is valid.

Comment: Yep. Why do you care, may we ask...?

Answer (score 6):

From the introduction paragraph to Chapter 3 of the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html):

> For example, the memory layout of
>   run-time data areas, **the
>   garbage-collection algorithm used**, and
>   any internal optimization of the Java
>   virtual machine instructions (for
>   example, translating them into machine
>   code) are **left to the discretion of
>   the implementor**. [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and not only that, each JVM can contain more than one garbage collection strategy:

- [Sun](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/)
- [JRockit](http://edocs.bea.com/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html)
- [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ibmjava2/)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely vendor dependent. GCJ and the Sun VM use totally different garbage collectors, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Java VM Spec's don't say anything specific about garbage collection. Each vendor has their own implementation for performing GC. In fact, each vendor will have multiple GC  policies that can be best chosen for a particular task.

**Example**
A GC tuned for throughput may not be good for real-time systems since they will have erratic (and often longer) pause times which are not predictable. Non-predictability is a killer for real-time application.

Some GC's such as the ones from Oracle and IBM are very tunable and can be tune based on your application's run-time memory characteristics.

The internals of GC are not too complicated at a higher level. Many algorithms that began in the early days of LISP are still in use today.

Read this (http://nd.edu/~dthain/courses/cse40243/spring2006/gc-survey.pdf "GC Introduction") for a good introduction to Garbage Collection at a moderately high-level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Java VirtualMachine  Specification  don't say anything specific about garbage collection. Each vendor has their own implementation for performing the task.
each can  automatically calls garbage collector, then we didn't need manual calls for garbage collection